# Maven in 5 Minutes issue

Tags: maven, powershell

I'm following [Maven in 5 Minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) manual with the following:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

I got the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.160s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Dec 10 16:27:55 ICT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (
D:\experiment\maven). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following arti
cles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

MORE INFO:

```
PS D:\experiment\maven> ping http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/2.2/maven-archetype-plugin-2.2.pom
Ping request could not find host http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/2.2/maven-archetype-plugin-2.2.pom. Please check the name and try again.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.869s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Dec 10 19:03:37 ICT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (
D:\experiment\maven). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MissingProjectException: The goal you specified requires a project to exe
cute but there is no POM in this directory (D:\experiment\maven). Please verify you invoked Maven fr
om the correct directory.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:89)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following arti
cles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

Comment: That is odd.  I just tried the **exact** command and it created a Maven project called `my-app` without any errors.  Can you confirm that you are issuing this command from a directory that isn't already a Maven project?  If you are new to Maven it is best you try these things from an empty directory.

Answer (score 22):

I am using Windows 7 SP1.

I was having the problem because I ran it using PowerShell.

It works fine when I ran it using CMD.EXE.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: It would be nice to add that information to your question (or even the title of your question), because that information is the interesting one here. Fine that it works now for you.

Comment: Clever observation, I had the same issue.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same problem, and it looks like we have the similar setup

- Windows 7
- Powershell
- HTTP proxy

here is what I have to do:

1. Wrap all the `"-D..."` inside double quotes, e.g.

   ```
   mvn archetype:generate "-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes" "-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart" "-DgroupId=com.mycompany.app" "-DartifactId=my-app"
   ```
2. Make sure you have `"HTTP_PROXY"` set properly in your envrironment variables
   (check it by typing `"echo $Env:HTTP_PROXY"`)

Comment: I like this answer better than the suggestion to use CMD.EXE because this is a solution instead of a workaround. Thanks, it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should follow the advice of the error message. Call Maven with the additional flags to get more information.

Second, you should ensure that your internet connection is working from the command line. Are you able for example to download `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/2.2/maven-archetype-plugin-2.2.pom` from your browser? If not, Maven is not able to download the necessary plugins, and so the normal bootstrapping that is necessary before your project can be build is not done. Check if your browser is using a proxy, and you don't have defined an environment variable `HTTP_PROXY`. If that is the case, define in the shell you are using your  variable `HTTP_PROXY` by the command:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://<my.proxy.host>:<port>
```

with the right values for `my.proxy.host` and `port`. If that works then well, define the environment variable for the system, so that every open shell has that environment variable defined.

Please add that information to your question, and sorry for the wrong advice to call `ping http://....`, that cannot work.

Comment: HTTP_PROXY is not defined. Also, my browser does use proxy. I am using Windows 7 SP1

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error and tried using double quotes to wrap all `-D` and it worked for me..

Example:

```
mvn archetype:create "-DarchetypeGroupId=org.springframework.ws" "-DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-ws-archetype" "-DarchetypeVersion=2.1.4.RELEASE" "-DgroupId=com.mycompany.hr" "-DartifactId=holidayService"
```

Comment: If this resolves the issue mainly depends on your shell and similar factors.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you are running "mvn compile" from POM directory and that is why it is asking for POM.

If so, simply go to directory where pom is located and then fire "mvn install" or any other Maven commands.

Answer (score 0):

It just took me 75 minutes to create a Maven quickstart project on Windows 10 using PowerShell in batch mode. Apparently I made three different mistakes.

Do the following:

- Provide all mandatory parameters or batch mode won't work. This is poorly documented in the [official Maven tutorial](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html), but correctly documented [here](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/examples/generate-batch.html):

  - `-B` for batch mode or `-DinteractiveMode=false` instead
  - `-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes`
  - `-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart`
  - `-DarchetypeVersion=1.1`
  - `-DgroupId=com.example`
  - `-DartifactId=app`
  - `-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT`
  - `-Dpackage=com.example.project`
- In PowerShell you have to use double quotes around every parameter, e.g. `"-DgroupId=com.example"`
- Don't use line breaks in your `archetype:generate` command

Full example:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B "-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes" "-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart" "-DarchetypeVersion=1.1" "-DgroupId=com.example" "-DartifactId=app" "-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT" "-Dpackage=com.example.project"
```