# Maven 3: Maven in 5 minutes "mvn archetype:generate..." command NOT WORKING

Tags: java, maven-3

I installed Maven 3.1.1 for the first time. In the "Maven in 5 Minutes" getting-started guide

http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

it says to verify the installation with

`mvn --version`

I got the expected response:

```
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 11:22:22-0400)
Maven home: C:\applications\programming\apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.6.0_17, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\applications\programming\java_6_17\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

In the next step, under "Creating a project" it says to create a new directory, open a command prompt in that directory, and execute

`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false`

I created a directory called `xjmaven`, ran the command in it, and it's not working. This is the response:

```
[R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\xjmaven]mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=xbnjava -DartifactId=XBN-Java -Darchetype ArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.251s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Nov 23 12:11:56 EST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/4M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\xjmaven). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

I looked up the parameters `groupId`, `artifactId` and `archetypeArtifactId`, and have tried some different values (as you can see above), but I still get the same BUILD FAILURE response.

I manually put the `pom.xml` file (from in the same webpage) in the xjmaven directory, and ran it again. It downloaded a bunch of stuff (although not to `xjmaven`), but then failed with this message:

```
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/true/1.0/true-1.0.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Skipping Maven Quick Start Archetype
[INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 45.047s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Nov 23 12:04:01 EST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/17M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project XBN-Java: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:true:1.0) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Repeating the command gives this response:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Quick Start Archetype 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ XBN-Java >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ XBN-Java <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ XBN-Java ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Skipping Maven Quick Start Archetype
[INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.444s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Nov 23 12:04:32 EST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/14M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project XBN-Java: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:true:1.0) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I deleted `pom.xml` (it's the only file in the directory...the stuff it downloaded is not there), and started over again. Everything happens (badly) as I write above.

---

I remember trying Maven a few years ago, and could also not get past the getting-started stage.

If anyone has some advice on how to get past this, it would be appreciated. Really frustrated.

Comment: You have a space that should not be there in `-Darchetype ArtifactId`. That said, you'd better learn Gradle, which is not only a much better tool, but also has a much better documentation.

Comment: Am trying Gradle now. Never heard of it before. I'm actually working through the tutorials, which is a step up compared to Maven. My first impression is that it is dog slow, but I'm hoping that it's just a matter of tweaking configuration. Thanks for the tip. Would still like to get Maven working...

Comment: If you're an Intellij Idea user, then this might be the shortest path: [Creating and importing Maven projects](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_and_importing_Maven_projects).

Comment: @user2736496 I used the same command that you have mentioned here and it seems to work fine for me. Can you repeat the process but this time delete your .m2/ folder and issue the same command but in a fresh directory.

Comment: @user2736496: make sure to activate the gradle daemon. This is what makes it much faster (http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html). But even without daemon, gradle is a bit slow to start, but that doesn't matter much when you have a large build with many modules and hundreds of tests, and that Gradle skips most of it because it supports incremental builds whereas Maven always goes through all the steps.

Comment: I will give that a try @JB Nizet, as with the other suggestions on getting Maven to work. Thanks again.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49353946/1492329

Answer (score 79):

Maybe you are using Windows PowerShell?

If so, you'll need to put quotes around the parameter definitions:

```
mvn archetype:generate "-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes" "-DgroupId=com.mycompany.app" "-DartifactId=my-app"
```

Comment: From user [Jean Metz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4388846/jean-metz) (who doesn't have enough rep to post a comment yet): I just had the same problem using Windows Power Shell, and the solution as stated above by Ergwun, is to use quotes around the parameter definitions.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, however it was on windows 10 command line. Ergwun's solution fixed the problem across both cli.

Answer (score 4):

You have some syntactical errors while executing the `generate` goal. Moreover, you need not create the pom.xml or any dir sturcture. You will notice that the `generate` goal creates a directory with the same name given as the artifactId.

e.g. you are missing the convention like `-DgroupId` should be com.company.app (not a big issue though), having space in `-Darchetype ArtifactId`, etc.

I just tried below and it worked :

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue on powershell. I switched to command prompt and executed the same command and it works fine. Command that works on command prompt: mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.myapp-DartifactId=hellomaven -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false

The one that runs on powershell:
mvn archetype:generate "-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes" "-DgroupId=com.myapp" "-DartifactId=my-app"